# Proof that the following limit equals $0$

Tags: calculus, limits

I have the following limit:

$$\lim_{n\to\infty} \left[\frac{\cos(n)+t\sin(n)}{e^{tn}}\right]$$

I wish to show that the limit equals $0$ rigorously. I have a good sense that it equals zero by taking the Taylor series expansion of the top, and comparing with that of the bottom. (The magnitude of the terms are the same, but the numerator has alternating signs, whereas the denominator is strictly positive. I should say; assume that $t>0$.)

I'm not sure however, whether that approach can be made rigorous. Other than that I am at a loss to prove it by a theorem or definition.

Comment: hint: use squeeze theorem to prove it

Comment: Hint: Notice that $-\sqrt{1+t^2} \leq \cos(n)+t\sin(n) \leq \sqrt{1+t^2}$, for every $t>0$, and for every $n$. The Squeeze Theorem would finish it.

Comment: Oh that makes a lot of sense; thanks a ton for all the help, everyone!

Comment: By the way, while the assumption $t>0$ is absolutely essential to proving the limit, it is not needed for the bounds I gave. And if you used the bounds $-1-|t|\leq \cos(n)+t\sin(n)\leq 1+|t|$, this is also true for $t\in\mathbb{R}$ (and is a simple modification of the bounds used in the answer below)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Note that $-1-t\leq\cos(n)+t\sin(n)\leq 1+t$

So we can use the squeeze theorem:

$$0=\lim_{n\to\infty} \frac{-1-t}{e^{tn}}\leq \lim_{n\to\infty} \frac{\cos(n)+t\sin(n)}{e^{tn}}\leq \lim_{n\to\infty} \frac{1+t}{e^{tn}}=0$$